# should facebook pixel run always?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am paying to facebook for signup completed using a pixel in my mk campaign, this pixel code should run always? also if traffic referral is not facebook ex. direct traffic.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because facebook is enabled to detect traffic referrer including between devices.
See
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10153190388971268